# 'first monday previous month' strtotime confusion

Tags: php, strtotime

Today is 2015-05-14

Why does

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first monday previous month'))
```

return

```
string(10) "2015-04-18"
```

I expected this to return 2015-04-06 - first Monday of previous month.

Comment: It's because previous month is `2015-04-14`, add `of` before `previous month`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `of` in the `datetime` string. Try with -

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first monday of previous month'));
```

[Docs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this..

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('First Monday of ' . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 months") ) ));
```